# Documenting File Naming Conventions

Tags: documentation, naming-conventions, filenames, conventions

I'm writing down some documentation on file naming of configuration files, and I don't know whether this question belongs here as it's not code-related, but here it goes.

So I want to describe how to name files and I have something along the lines of:

{client_name}-{product_name}-{season}-{id}.yaml

Now my question is since client_name, product_name, season, and id are not necessarily variable names, just used to describe what string goes where, should there be underscores in multiple word descriptions, or should I keep them separated with space, like:

{client name}-{product name}-{season}-{id}.yaml

My concern is that because of the underscores, someone may think they are variables and look for them somewhere in the code of the projects, instead of in other linked documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed if your naming system do not vary too much, it is evidently failing on its purpose.

I hardly can find an standard on this, but some widespread use is to have the following structure, with more or less modifications

```
[Project Name]-[Department]-[Doc.Type]-[Number]-[Revision]
```

The last kind of structure works well for definite, unchangeable work structures. Check the [CERN LHC Document Name Structure](https://lhc-proj-qawg.web.cern.ch/CD-ROM-v4-0/Quality/QA202.pdf) as an example for this.

From other side, for more dynamic but flat environments, with documents generated day by day, and even, auto generated by systems like cameras or dataloggers, something exposing the specific timestamp are more useful, in the date format `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYY-MM-DD`, or even with timestamps extending to hours, minutes or seconds for more automated processes `YYYYMMDDhhmmss` based on the ISO Date:

```
[Date]-[Document Name]
```

Unfortunately there is not any Standard Naming Convention nor under the ISO-7001 or under any other Standard related to Naming Systems, and it is much left to the Quality Management System to specify the structure to use.

[image: CERN LHC Document Name Structure]